# unable to load mod_wsgi in apache

Tags: apache, wamp, mod-wsgi

I Have searched a lot to find the solution but i am unable to find one

whenever i add these lines in my httpd.conf file

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

my wamp just don't turn online.Nor does it shows any error.
I hav added the mod_wsgi.so file in the correct folder.
Although i have 64 bit windows but i tried adding both 32 bit and 64 bit mod_wsgi but both didn't work.

Need a great help.
PS:i just want to run a simple logic in python by taking input from a webpage and showing output on same page.If someone could suggest some other way...

Comment: Does something appear into the error.log?

Comment: That is strage, by the way in windows I would expect the file extension dll and not the Unix one so.

Comment: well whenever i search for mod_wsgi .so files are shown for windows and even other modules in my modules folder are also .so..so i guess they are supported by windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of Python, Apache and mod_wsgi.so must be either 32 bit or 64 bit. You cannot mix such that some are 32 bit and some are 64 bit. Also, the Python must be installed for all users on the system and not just the user you installed it as. The mod_wsgi.so must be compiled for the Apache version you are using.

Comment: How to check python for all users or not? if `not` how to make it for all users.

Comment: It is a check box on the Python installer unless it has been changed in recent years. If you don't know, uninstall Python and reinstall and make sure you check the box. If you use a batch installer, I understand installing for all users may not be the default and some command line option is required.

Comment: Thanks. It really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Apache 2.4.2 ?

`mod_wsgi 3.3` doesn't support `Apache 2.4`

Comment: Correct. Need mod_wsgi 3.4 for Apache 2.4, but doesn't have to be that. I know of know where where mod_wsgi 3.4 binaries are available for Windows. I am unlikely to be providing them myself this time.